# Pod Error: bitnami mysql helm chart on MacOS

Tags: mysql, docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, rancher-desktop

1. In my local environment when using Rancher Desktop on MacOS
2. With default configurations
3. Run `helm install my-release bitnami/mysql`
4. See Error...

```
% kubectl get pods                     
NAME                 READY   STATUS             RESTARTS        AGE
my-release-mysql-0   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   6 (3m12s ago)   8m57s

% kubectl logs my-release-mysql-0
/usr/lib: './var/cache/ldconfig': Permission denied
/usr/lib: './proc/tty/driver': Permission denied
/usr/lib: './root': Permission denied
/usr/lib: './etc/ssl/private': Permission denied
mysql Wed Aug 24 23:07:43 UTC 2022INFO  ==> ** Starting MySQL **
2022-08-24T23:07:43.299737Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010939] [Server] Failed to get absolute path of program executable --defaults-file=/opt/bitnami/mysql/conf/my.cnf
2022-08-24T23:07:43.933997Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010918] [Server] 'default_authentication_plugin' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use authentication_policy instead.
2022-08-24T23:07:43.934191Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] --defaults-file=/opt/bitnami/mysql/conf/my.cnf (mysqld 8.0.30) starting as process 1
2022-08-24T23:07:43.953718Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013242] [Server] --character-set-server: 'utf8' is currently an alias for the character set UTF8MB3, but will be an alias for UTF8MB4 in a future release. Please consider using UTF8MB4 in order to be unambiguous.
2022-08-24T23:07:43.954132Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013244] [Server] --collation-server: 'utf8mb3_general_ci' is a collation of the deprecated character set UTF8MB3. Please consider using UTF8MB4 with an appropriate collation instead.
2022-08-24T23:07:43.956530Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file /bitnami/mysql/data/mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2022-08-24T23:07:43.956655Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /bitnami/mysql/data/ is case insensitive
2022-08-24T23:07:43.957378Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013276] [Server] Failed to set datadir to '/bitnami/mysql/data/' (OS errno: 2 - No such file or directory)
2022-08-24T23:07:43.958983Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-08-24T23:07:43.962276Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] --defaults-file=/opt/bitnami/mysql/conf/my.cnf: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30)  Source distribution.
```

**NOTE:** When I run this same thing on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine it works just fine.

Comment: the volume storage isn't writable

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I know but why? I'm thinking rancher desktop permission issues or something. It worked a couple of weeks ago on this machine and works on my Ubuntu machine np.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a permissions issue. Once I had admin permissions set properly, I updated RD and everything worked as it should.